# Open User Page in Tiktok app on Android with Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there something similar to the Soundcloud Uri ("soundcloud://users:" + "soundcloud_username") that allows an app user to open the Tiktok app and go to another user's page, like the Soundcloud code below?

Soundcloud code reference: Force a Soundcloud track to open in Soundcloud app on Android

```
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("soundcloud://users:" + "soundcloud_username"));
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://soundcloud.com/"+string_soundcloudLink_profile)));
        }
```

Comment: i have same question any update @Carl   ?

Comment: @verbs no luck so far :/ we could contact TikTok maybe. Any other ideas??

Comment: hey @carl I solve this issue , please check code which i posted below but i am working with xamarin.android so please do some minor changes for Native android . and if you have any other question regarding that please ask me

Answer (score 1):

```
private fun openTikTokProfile() {
    val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("https://www.tiktok.com/@${username}")
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)

    intent.setPackage("com.zhiliaoapp.musically")

    if (intent.resolveActivity(requireActivity().packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey I found the solution But its in xamarin.android

```
private void urlclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                PackageManager manager = PackageManager;
                var U =Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://vm.tiktok.com/tiktokulr");///Add URL of you tiktok account  
                Intent i;
                Intent icheck;
                try
                {
                    i = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, U);

                    icheck = manager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.zhiliaoapp.musically");
                    if (icheck == null)
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "please install tiktok in your phone", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        StartActivity(i);
                    }

                }
                catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException exp)
                {

                }
```

Comment: What do you consider by `tiktokulr` within your link `http://vm.tiktok.com/tiktokulr`? And are you able to open a final link via a browser? If so, wouldn't it be an 404 error page?

Comment: @ivan8m8 tiktok url = profile url of user . go to user profile click on 3 dots of upper right corner click on share profile and you get profile url of particular user

Comment: This works! Thanks so much @vebs!! Any idea how to just open the tiktok app to it's homepage??